# Изменить position дива через js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Доброго времени суток, знатоки. Кратко к делу. Есть див с картинкой:

```
<div class="slide1" id="1"><img src="img/1.jpg" height="400"></div>
```

У него есть такой css

```
.slide1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    display: block;
}
```

И есть, к примеру, такой скрипт после дива

```
<script>
if(confirm("crhsnm")) {
    document.getElementById(1).style.position.left= "5px;";
}
</script>
```

Мне надо, что бы при нажатии конфирма ок - менялась позиция дива, но как правильно прописать этот гетЭлемент я не нашел. Пожалуйста, подскажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых строку

`document.getElementById(1).style.position.left= "5px;";` замените на

```
document.getElementById(1).style.left= "5px";
```

Во-вторых вы не смещаете div на 5рх влево. Вы задаете свойство left = 5px. То есть было 200рх, а тут бац и стало 5.